In the addition $\begin{array}{c|c|c}+ A \ A\ A \\ \ \ B\ B\ B \\ \hline A \ A\ A\ C \end{array}$, $A,B,C$ each denotes a digit. Find them.

In the addition $\begin{array}{c|c|c}+ A \ A\ A \\ \ \  B\ B\ B \\ \hline A \ A\  A\  C \end{array}$, $A,B,C$ each denotes a digit. Find them.

The solution says, "First of all $A$ denotes $1$ because no other digit can appear as a carry in the thousands position of the result".
Can someone explain to me what this means? Because I don't understand how $A$ can only be $1$ and not any other number ($2$~$9$).

Adding two numbers which are smaller than $10^n$ for some number $n \in \Bbb N$ will always produce a number strictly smaller than $2\cdot10^n$, meaning its first digit in the decimal expansion will always be a $1$

I think I got confused because I started from the right side and thought $A+B=[\ ]C$ and how that carries over.


Can someone explain to me what this means? Because I don't understand how A can only be 1  and not any other number (2~9).

You have two three-digit numbers that add to a four-digit number.  The largest possible sum is $999 + 999 = 1998$.  (Or, if you assume the restriction $A\ne B$, $999 + 888 = 1887$.)  So this “carry” digit ($A$) can only be $1$.  (Unless you allow leading $0$, but alphanumeric puzzles like these typically don't.)
